# Best way to Swipe through Photos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile, sdk

im trying to make a image gallery and the user swipes through views like on the Photo app on the iphone. i heard page control was very good but it has a limit of 20 bullets and i need more swipes. what would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) framework.  You're job is [almost done for you](http://github.com/blog/389-three20-iphone-ui-goodness).

Answer (score 0):

Either the three20 as said or a scroll view (without paging) and an uiimageview inside that with uiimages.